# Why Deep Learning needs to be performed in Graphical representations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

Why do we bother about devising new Deep Learning methods, which is to be applied on graphical representation of data? Why not use the traditional Deep Learning methods in the adjacency matrix representation of graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Same could have been said about image data, but CNNs were born. Models that exploit the structure of the underlying data are likely to be more successful than generic methods.

Answer (score 1):

Because traditional deep learning methods do not take into account a crucial property of the adjacency matrix representation: node permutation equivariance.
One axiom of deep learning is that inductive biases tend to help.
This was the case with convolutions in computer vision, recurrence in timeseries, trigonometric bases in implicit neural representations.
So it made sense to incorporate this into the architecture of Graph Neural Networks, in the hopes that it would help with performance and/or efficiency.

Some of these operations can also be directly derived from group theory (see [Geometric Deep Learning: Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges, 10.48550/arXiv.2104.13478](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2104.13478) and [Gauge Equivariant Convolutional Networks and the Icosahedral CNN, 10.48550/arXiv.1902.04615](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1902.04615) for examples).